# HorizontalListView performance issues : Calls inflates for every subview

Tags: android, listview, horizontallist, pulse

I'm making a Pulse kind of UI for my app. For this I'm using `HorizontalListView` class as given [here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). However, this class has performance issues and delivers a noticeable lag.

To confirm this I assessed it using `TraceView Profiler` and found that this class doesn't reuse views altogether and calls `inflate()` method for every call inside `getView()`.

Here is how I'm designing the adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final BaseAssets baseAsset = baseAssetsList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.newLabel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_new);
        viewHolder.assetImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView newLabel;
    ImageView assetImage;
 }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? If not, please suggest me workarounds to improve performance. Possibly some other library you would have tried or any way to reuse views in my current library. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're never calling `convertView.setTag(viewHolder);` in the case the `convertView` is null. You cant retrieve the `ViewHolder` without first setting it as the tag.

**EDIT:**

Other than that your code seems fine, my best guess would be that the problem lies in the implementation of the `HorizontalListView`.

I looked at its source (HorizontalListView.java) and if you can experiment with the source, try checking if `mRemovedViewQueue` is empty before it makes any calls to `mAdapter.getView`.If it is, then its not handling the recycling properly.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I deleted that line just to simplify my code here. In my actual code its there. Apology for confusion !

Comment: Updated my answer. I doubt it'll help though. Sorry haha

Comment: No problem..I'll give a try though !
Are you a student ?

Comment: For the time being, yes I am.